# Missing or invalid primary key

Tags: python, sqlite, trac

I create my trac enviromnets using a sqlite database, it works very well.

Now i want to get some information directly from the database and i'm using C# to do it using [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). The problem i have is an error in the designer cause the tables don't have primary keys.

After get this error i went and noticed that all tables that have more than one primary key defined in the [schema](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/db_default.py) were not 'converted' to sqlite, that information is lost.

I believe the problem is in [sqlite_backend.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py) but python isn't my speciality and i'm in a hurry so if you can guide me to a quick fix.

**UPDATE (litle more detail):**

System.Data.SQLite

> "Support for the ADO.NET 3.5 Entity
> Framework Supports nearly all the
> entity framework functionality that
> Sql Server supports, and passes 99% of
> the tests in MS's EFQuerySamples demo
> application."
>
> Visual Studio 2005/2008 Design-Time
> Support You can add a SQLite
> connection to the Server Explorer,
> create queries with the query
> designer, drag-and-drop tables onto a
> Typed DataSet and more!

When i drag the tables to the designer, some tables don't make it to the designer. The reasos is,

> "The table/view 'main.attachment' does
> not have a primary key defined and no
> valid primary key could be inferred.
> This table/view has been excluded. To
> use the entity, you will need to
> review your schema, add the correct
> keys, and uncomment it."

The problem is this, no entitys = no data.

**UPDATE (more info):**

My objective isn't change datamodel.

In [trac schema](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema) the tables *attachment*, *auth_cookie*, *enum*, *node_change*, *permission*, *session*, *session_attribute*, *ticket_change*, *ticket_custom* are defined with primary keys.

When i browse the file trac.db (default) the tables aren't defined with the primary_keys specified in the schema.

I want a solution to solve this litle *feature* of trac sqlite db.
I don't think it's the best solution edit the table after creation to add pk that aren't created.

**UPDATE**

Any ideia?!

Comment: I think you need to describe what you are doing in a bit more detail... I don't understand your goal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "designer", but it sounds like it can't support tables without primary keys.  What "data" do you need to get from the database?  Can you get it without this designer?

Comment: The designer is the one from visual studio that generate code to the entity objects

Comment: The data i want to get its all the wiki pages and the content (not only but this is the one giving me problems). 

Without the designer is too much work and i dont know how to do it :S

Comment: Are you trying to run a query?  Lots of people on here can help with query writing...

Comment: Are you trying to run a query?  Lots of people on here can help with query writing...  I wouldn't try modifying the schema to fit the designer.  Can you use a different graphical query tool to get at your data?  http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i'm not saying to change datamodel.

In http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema the tables attachment, auth_cookie, enum, node_change, permission, session, session_attribute, ticket_change, ticket_custom are defined with primary keys.

when i browse the file trac.db (default) the tables aren't defined with the primary_keys specified in the schema.

Comment: You aren't required to define primary keys in SQLite.  The fact that the designer is asking for primary keys is the designer's problem, not the database schema.  I'd say you have two options:  I'd try adding those keys to the database (which Trac wouldn't like by its db code - just guessing), or learn a different way to get at your data aside from a crutch like the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Trac Database API. It's written in Python, but you could probably rewrite it in C# fairly easily. At the very least it'll give you a starting point for finding your solution.
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseApi